# Почему нельзя поменять переменную родительского класса через функцию

Tags: python, ооп, классы, объекты

*Добрый день. Прошу подсказать или дать ссылку где бы объяснялось почему происходит следующее:*

1. Первый пример кода:

```
class parent:
    x = 1

    def change_all(self, value):
        parent.x = value

parent.change_all(3)
```

Получаем ошибку в Pycharm:
`TypeError: parent.change_all() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`

2. Второй пример кода:

```
class parent:
    x = 1

    def change_all(self, value):
        parent.x = value

child = parent()

child.change_all(3)
```

Никаких ошибок нет, все работает, x меняется на 3.

Вопрос: почему можно поменять х через функцию выполненную для объекта класса, но нельзя через функцию для самого класса? Подозреваю что это связано с принципами ООП, но объяснение именно вот этого момента найти не смог, прощу поделиться ссылкой или дать направление куда смотреть

Comment: Потому что в первом случае не создан экземпляр класса и, обращаясь к типу, а не объекту, вы вызываете функцию и должны объяснить ей кто такой этот `self`. Когда же экземпляр объекта создан, как во втором случае, Python знает что это за self и куда его девать.

Comment: Можете посмотреть сюда <https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/7.1.php>

Comment: Чтобы обращаться к методам класса без создания их экземпляра нужно сделать методы статическими. И переменные, которые в статических методах используются тоже должны быть статическими

Comment: Я думал тут про наследование что-то будет. То, о чем вы говорите - класс и экземляр, а не родитель и "ребенок". Заголовок должен быть "Почему нельзя поменять переменную класса через функцию экземляра, не создавая тот самый экземпляр" - тогда должно быть понятно, что не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы первый пример работал, вам нужно сделать метод либо классовым, либо статическим, тогда всё будет функционировать нормально, выглядеть это будет вот так для метода класса:

```
class parent:
    x = 1
    @classmethod
    def change_all(cls, value):
        parent.x = value

parent.change_all(3)
print(parent.x)
```

Вывод

```
3
```

Или же если делать метод статическим:

```
class parent:
    x = 1
    @staticmethod
    def change_all(value):
        parent.x = value

parent.change_all(3)
print(parent.x)
```

Вывод

```
3
```